# Find where value is assigned to a variable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Environment: C# / MVC / Entity framework / visual studio.
I have a variable name, used in 3 tables (so 3 entities) as column name and many "models" classes.

The bug: in some odd intermittent cases, the value is reset to null after it was actually saved as numeric.

Question: I want to know where all the variable appears on left side of assignment or otherwise getting value. This itself is a generic problem worth knowing answer.

Unfortunately the variable name itself appears in 789 lines of 164 files in VS solution.

Comment: You've shown no code so any suggestions would be pure guesswork but convert your “value” to a property if it is not already, and put a breakpoint or null check or something in the property setter.

Comment: I've had situations like this in the past, I just made the variable a property with get/setters, and had it log when it was set

Comment: I am not sure what code is expected, I want to find lines in code, VS or other tool, so that I can find statements like entityX.columnY = assignvalue. If volume of lines was low, I would do Shift-F12 and find all references and inspect manually. Reason to specify I am using EF is to make it clear there are no getter/setters for me; though as a last resort, yes. The comments and answers are so elementary that insult my intelligence. This is my first and last question SO. Bye.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in a custom setter to log all changes including the calling method.  There may be some performance implications, but you might find it helpful for debugging, and you only have to make the change in one place, not in 789:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            // using System.Diagnostics
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); // get the current stack trace
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1); // get the last frame
            Debug.WriteLine($"My Property Set by {sf.GetMethod().Name}.  New value: {value}");

            _myProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given much information, however in visual studio you can right click  on a variable name/property and find all references inside the solution.

I would advise finding all references on a property of a model and keep doing that until you find what you are looking for.